# Homotopies of CW complexes relative an n-skeleton

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

I was wondering if the following were true or not. Suppose $f:(X,X^n)\rightarrow (X,X^n)$ and $g:(X,X^n)\rightarrow (X,X^n)$ are homotopic. Does it neccesarily follow that $f$ and $g$ are homotopic rel $X^n$.

The reason I am asking is that I am trying to prove that the $n$-skeletons of homotopy equivalent CW complexes without cells of dimension $n+1$ are also homotopy equivalent. What I have so far is the following. 
 Note that this is exercise 14 page 359 in Hatcher.

**Proof**: Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$
  be a homotopy equivalence and let $g:Y\rightarrow X$
  be its counterpart. Then we can homotope these maps to get cellular maps $\tilde{f}$
  and $\tilde{g}$
 ,respectively. In particular $\tilde{f}:(X,X^{n})\rightarrow(Y,Y^{n})$
  and $\tilde{g}:(Y,Y^{n})\rightarrow(X,X^{n})$
 . And furthermore, we have $\tilde{f}\circ\tilde{g}\approx f\circ g\approx\text{Id}_{Y}$
  and $\tilde{g}\circ\tilde{f}\approx g\circ f\approx\text{Id}_{X}$
 . The key thing we need is to ensure that the homotopies are taken relative $X^{n}$
  and $Y^{n}$
 . Then taking restrictions on our maps gives us the desired result.
I'm assuming that I have to work in the fact that the $CW$ complexes don't contain $n+1$ cells, but I don't see how that gets worked into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isn't true in general.  For instance, if $X=X^n$, then you are just asking whether any two homotopic maps from a $\leq n$-dimensional CW-complex to itself are equal, which is obviously false for most such $X$.

Comment: Then may I ask can we somehow use the fact since our CW complex doesn't contain $n+1$ cells we may obtain such a homotopy?

Comment: You don't need your homotopies to be homotopies _rel_ $X^n$ and $Y^n$; you only need them to be homotopies which restrict to homotopies $X^n\times I\to X^n$ and $Y^n\times I\to Y^n$ (i.e., every stage of the homotopy preserves the $n$-skeleton). You can do this by applying (relative) cellular approximation to the homotopy itself.

Comment: So I thought that was one way to do it, but then I don't see why we need the fact that our CW complex doesn't have $n+1$ cells.

Comment: The key point is that $X^n\times I$ is only contained in the $(n+1)$-skeleton of $X\times I$, not the $n$-skeleton, so a priori you would only know that your cellular approximation maps $X^n\times I$ to $X^{n+1}$.

Comment: I see. Thanks Wofsey.